# Qt QWizard how to remove subtitle area

Tags: qt

I need to remove subtitle area from QWizard page.Pls let me know is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks,
Bhaskar

Answer (score 0):

Use the `QWizard::IgnoreSubTitles` option:

```
wizard->setOption(QWizard::IgnoreSubTitles, true);
```